# How to integrate FourSquare Venues using angular Angucomplete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foursquare

I am trying to integrate **foursquare** venues in my angular app using angular **angucomplete**, But The **datafield** in **angucomplete** requires **array of object** and response from **FourSquare** come in array of array and among these inner arrays there is one array of venues. So Can anyone tell how to do this in angucomplete?

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Can you please show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scratching head for these much days I am able to integrate **FourSquare Venues in Angucomplete**. To do this I have used **Local method of Angucomplete** and On every enter of character I have used **onKeyUp** method and get the entered string and fired a query and shown result in array of object form by directing array to specific array of objects of locations.

Happy Coding :-)